# Macro for optimization level (ARMCC V6)

Tags: c, macros, compiler-options, armv6, armcc

There are predefined macros such as `__OPTIMIZE__` (defined in all optimizing compilations) and `__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__` (defined if the compiler is optimizing for size).

I use these macros to check if the correct optimization level is set for the release target, if not I print out a warning.

Is there a possibility to check whether the optimization level `-Ofast` is set or not?
Possibly something like `__OPTIMIZE_FAST__` or `__OPTIMIZE_SPEED__`.

Comment: So... what research did you do? Did you read your compiler documentation?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. According to my research and knowledge, there is no macro available. My hope is, that somebody else would know more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the [ARMCC command line options](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0472/m/compiler-command-line-options?lang=en) and it seems there's no `-Ofast` like in many other compilers. However if the behavior is the same as in GCC/Clang/ICC... then `-Ofast` is essentially just `-O3` with [`--fpmode=fast`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0472/m/compiler-command-line-options/--fpmode-model?lang=en) so you can check it with [`__FP_FAST`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0472/j/compiler-specific-features/predefined-macros), probably in conjunction with `__OPTIMISE_LEVEL`

In GCC you can use [`__FAST_MATH__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). [`__NO_MATH_ERRNO__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) may also be used although it may not be an exact match because that'll also be defined if `-fno-math-errno` is specified

```
#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
    printf("Optimized\n");

    #ifdef __ARMCC_VERSION
        #if defined(__FP_FAST) && __OPTIMISE_LEVEL >= 3
            printf("-Ofast ARMCC\n");
        #endif
    #elif defined(__GNUC__)
        #if defined(__FAST_MATH__)
//      #if defined(__NO_MATH_ERRNO__)
            printf("-Ofast GNUC\n");
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```